# Cannot find css on blueprint with url_for

Tags: python, flask

I keep getting this error:

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: ('mainsite.mainsite_static', {'filename': 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'}, None)
```

The blueprint is declared on my views.py as:

```
mainsite = Blueprint("mainsite", __name__, static_folder='mainsite_static')
```

The css file is called from the layout.html template as:

```
    <link href="{{url_for('.mainsite_static', filename='vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

The folder structure is:

```
mainsite
|_views.py
|_templates
| |_layout.html  
|_mainsite_static
  |_vendor
    |_bootstrap
      |_css
        |_boostrap.min.css
```

From all I can read, it should work. I renamed the folder, I added the static_folder parameter on the declaration of the Blueprint. There is nothing else with the same name. Added the . (tried as well with 'mainsite.mainsite_static' )

Finally, mainsite.mainsite_static appears on the url_map

```
<Rule '/mainsite_static/<filename>' (GET, OPTIONS, HEAD) -> mainsite.static>,
```

Comment: did you try <link href="{{url_for('mainsite.static', filename='vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> ?

Comment: I did not. Tried and it works. Even .static works. If you convert into answer, I will accept it.

Interesting that you still need to use static, instead of the folder name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work instead

```
<link href="{{url_for('mainsite.static', filename='vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

As you highlight in the url_map - the endpoint for mainsite_static folder is `mainsite.static` which can be used in your `url_for`s